# Can't get headers from angular $resource query response in Safari

Tags: angularjs, safari, http-headers, angular-resource

It works in other browsers (Chrome, FF, IE) but I can't get all headers form the response in the Safari browser. I try to get `X-Pagination-Total-Count` header returned by the server using this code.

```
  $scope.logs = LogService.query( {id: data.id, 'per-page': 5, page: 1, sort: '-id'}, function(data, headers) {
    console.log('headers',headers());
    $scope.totalLogsNumber = headers('X-Pagination-Total-Count');
  });
```

Console log shows that there is only one property in object returned by `headers()`: `content-type`.

I can see `X-Pagination-Total-Count` header in the response in the developer tools.

I have set this header in the server's `.htaccess` file

```
Header set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "X-Pagination-Total-Count, X-Pagination-Current-Page, X-Pagination-Page-Count, X-Pagination-Per-Page"
```

What's going on?

Comment: I realized that [Safari for Windows was supported till 2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history). That's why resigned supporting it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with Safari. As an alternative solution send data in response body instead of header.

Visit [angularJS response header access returns null in Safari Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453663/angularjs-response-header-access-returns-null-in-safari-browser)