# angularJS response header access returns null in Safari Browser

Tags: angularjs, safari, header, http-headers, response-headers

After $http request in angularJS, I could see any header sent with response in safari "Web Inspector" (OS: Windows 8). But same when I try to access like **headers('Authorization')** in **angularJS**, it returns **null**.

Tried by setting custom headers also, but when I access, I get **null** value. Our application login happens by validating the authorization header. Since it is returning null in Safari browser, not able to login only :(.

Anyone has come across this Safari browser issue and got solution? Please help..

Comment: Your question is confusing - `Authorization` is a request header - you won't be able to see it on a response.

Comment: Application sends a 'bearer token' in 'Authorization' header with login response. and any further request made to server will have this 'Authorization' header to authenticate in server.

Comment: What happens if you try to send the `bearer token` value in the response body from your server instead? It doesn't have to be in the header. You can then include it in the Authorize header for all subsequent requests.

Comment: 'bearer token' in response body is working out. I could read it and send same in subsequent 'Authorization' request headers. Is it not an issue to send 'bearer token' in response body, as a security concern?

Comment: Token value is just as readable by 3rd party interception in a header as it is in the body - use SSL to encrypt everything